# Storing JSON data in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database

I am new to rails and am a bit lost on how to take a JSON string from an API call and store it into my model.  I'm going around in circles trying to figure it out.

As an example I receive the following from my API call.

> {"FileType"=>nil, "Text"=>nil, "TextCode"=>nil, "Html"=>nil,
>   "HtmlCode"=>nil, "Rtf"=>nil, "RtfCode"=>nil, "CreditsRemaining"=>0,
>   "FileExtension"=>nil, "Pdf"=>nil, "PdfCode"=>nil,
>   "CandidateImage"=>nil, "CandidateImageExtension"=>nil,
>   "Code"=>"Error", "SubCode"=>"AuthenticationError", "Message"=>"Invalid
>   AccountId:  The 'AccountId' you provided is invalid.",
>   "ParsedDocument"=>nil}

I want to insert this into my **Resume** model so I created the following **Helper**.

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'base64'
require 'json'

    module ResumesHelper
        def parser

            FILE_NAME = "test.docx"

            # Perform a binary read of the entire file
            fileBuf = File.open(FILE_NAME,"rb") {|io| io.read}
            base64 = Base64.encode64(fileBuf)

            params = "{\"FileBytes\":" + "\"" + base64 + "\"," +
                  "\"AccountId\": \"MyID\",
                  \"ServiceKey\": \"MyKey\"}"           

            response = RestClient::Request.execute(
            method: :post,
            url: 'http://example/api',
            payload: params,
            headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
            )

            a_hash = JSON.parse(response)

            new_record = Resume.new
            new_record.attribute_1 = a_hash['Message']
            new_record.save

    end
```

I get an error that the script has an incorrect syntax. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: (1) You should post the error message as that can often be helpful, and (2) is that your actual code? If so, minimally, it looks like you don't close `def` with an `end`.

Comment: `\"ServiceKey\"` this part is probably wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do when I need to save JSON returns to process in the future.

1) migration
rails g migration AddJsonResponseToModel

```
#/db/migrate/20170518014529_add_json_response_to_model.rb
class AddJesonResponseToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :models, :json_response, :text
  end
end
```

2) controller or were ever you are getting the response

```
#app/controllers/models_controller.rb
class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    model = Model.find(params[:id])
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
        method: :post,
        url: 'http://example/api',
        payload: params,
        headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
    )
    model.json_response = response.to_json
    ...
    model.save
  end
end
```

I hope that this works for you :) 
Happy Hacking